# Probelm with Django manage.py runserver provides errors

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python and Django. I am trying to run my manage.py but i have this problem

```
enter code here
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\Nouha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in 
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Nouha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\Nouha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\Nouha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
 File "C:\Users\Nouha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
 module = import_module(entry)
File "C:\Users\Nouha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in 
 _find_and_load_unlocked
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp'
```

I tried all solutions in stackoverflow but I still have the same problem :( 
Can anyone help me please ?!

Comment: This error occurs when you set an app in your INSTALLED_APPS variable of your **settings.py**, and such app has not been created. Can you share the directories tree of your project?

Comment: Your app webapp is not installed in your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` list. I recommend you follow a tutorial such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website to get it right

Comment: here is my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webapp' ,
    'Personal' ,
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]